# Loop on object property (QML)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Qt complains at runtime when I use the following QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Rectangle
{
    color: palette.grey

    property var spotButtonFunctions :
    {
        'EditViewTool' : function() {switchToEditViewToolButton.source = "../View/Icons/icon_game.png";},
        'SelectTool'   : function() {switchToSelectToolButton.source = "../View/Icons/icon_game.png";}
    }

    property var greyButtonFunctions :
    {
        'EditViewTool' : function() {switchToEditViewToolButton.source = "../View/Icons/icon_settings.png";},
        'SelectTool'   : function() {switchToSelectToolButton.source = "../View/Icons/icon_info.png";}
    }

    // View update slots.
    function onNotifyCurrentToolSignal(currentToolName)
    {
        // Grey all tool buttons.
        for (x in greyButtonFunctions)
            greyButtonFunctions[x]();

        // Spot the current tool button.
        if (currentToolName !== "")
            spotButtonFunctions[currentToolName]();
    }
}
```

The error message is related to line `for (x in greyButtonFunctions)`:

> Error: Cannot assign QString to double

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning to the [`x property`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#x-prop) of `Item`.

If you want a local variable named x you have to do `for (var x in greyButtonFunctions)`